# Cartesian product of sets of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

If I have two sets A, B, which are sets of sets. Is there any abbreviated notation to write $$ \{ C \times D | C \in A \wedge D \in B\} $$ ?

Comment: That's pretty abbreviated as it is.  I don't think you can do better.  It's not any less abbreviated than the standard notation for defining the cartesian product of two sets (as $M\times N= \{(a,b)|a\in M; b\in N\}$; is $A\overline{\underline \circ}B = \{C\times D|C\in A; D\in B\}$ any less abbreviated?)

Comment: Oh.... I see what you are asking.  You are asking for notation. I don't know of any notation but you can make up your own.  I made up $A\overline{\underline \circ} B$ simply because it was simply mathjax that didn't look like anything else.

Comment: Like fleablood, I don't think there's a standard abbreviation for this one. I'd suggest $A \Box B$, because it's like a set of rectangles whose sides are chosen from $A$ and $B$.

Comment: One has similar notation with union. When you have a set A, which is a set of set and you want to unionize all the set that are elements of A you can simply write $$ \bigcup A $$.

Answer (score -1):

You can use $S = \{C \times D\;|\;C \in A \land D \in B\}$ and use $S$ or define $S[A:B]$ to mean that.